# find if a code exists in xml, using c#

Tags: c#, xml, dom

I am starting to work with xml and I am trying to know if there is a way to search a code in this. 
Here you are my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <doctors_hospital>
<doctor>
    <code>1757D</code>
    <name>one</name>
</doctor>
<doctor>
    <code>1169L</code>
    <name>two</name>
</doctor>
... continues xml
</doctors_hospital>
```

I want to look for the code "aab" using c#, and this is my code..

```
 var document =new  XmlDocument();
        document.Load("O:\\test\\doctor.xml");
  XmlNode doctor;
        XmlNode root = document.DocumentElement; 
        doctor = root.SelectSingleNode("/doctors_hospital/doctor/code='aab'");
```

I can not do this. any suggestion? thanks

Comment: _"I can not do this"_ -- Why not? What error do you get?

Comment: I get this error : Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `SelectingSingleNode` takes a standard XPath expression, what you want to use is

```
/doctors_hospital/doctor[code='aab']
```

This will select the entire `doctor` node with the matching `code` value.

Comment: thanks Jim! another question, is there any guide to help me to understand better the xmldocument class? for dummies jeje

Comment: The C# documentation?  C# tutorials? It's all on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `Jim`, alternatively you could also use `Linq` to `Xml` and do this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);       
var codeExist = doc.Descendants("code").Any(x=>(string)x.Value == "1169L");
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dGNQrw)

Comment: thanks! I will check more about Linq. In this moment I will get the answer from Jim. Thanks for your time Hari

Comment: Sure, I prefer that solution for beginners.

Comment: jajaja yea, I am just starting with xml